# Need some explanations on iptables appended rules

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, linux-networking

Here are some rules that I append to `filter` table, and I list the added output related to each one:

1. `$iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT`

and the output is:

```
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

The second command:

2. `$iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT`

And the appended rule to INPUT chain is the same as the first one:

```
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

As you see, I changed the source of packets from `eth0` to `eth1`, but I don't see it reflected in the appended rule. Can anybody explain me where is the difference made or how the `iptables` knows that first rule is related to `eth0` and second rule is related to `eth1`?

Thanks!

Comment: When you list the tables, try adding a `-v`

Comment: @JonLin Thanks! I see the Output very well. You can post your comment as answer I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you list the tables, try adding a `-v`, which will give you columns for the number of packets/bytes as well as the input and output interfaces.